# Pointing to a Library Across Platforms

Tags: c++, cmake

When working on a CMake project, I typically either use `pkg-config` to locate libraries, *or* download dependencies to a specific location on my system and hardcode these paths. This works well when using one machine, but makes things a hassle when switching between multiple machines, or even interchangeably developing on Linux and Windows.

It seems like a poor solution to simply expect libraries to be in a specific, hardcoded location (i.e. `C:\VulkanSDK\Some-Specific-Version-Number` and `C:\GLFW\`, as I have on windows) which varies depending on the host system, as this adds additional setup steps whenever someone clones a project to develop on a different machine. It also seems like a bad idea to explicitly include library sources and builds *within* my repository, or to use git submodules (since some libraries don't host builds with git.)

What's the best way to manage library dependencies like this cross-platform?

Comment: Did you have a look at [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html)?

Comment: @StanleyF. That still requires manual installation of the library to one of a few specific places on the system, which is still likely to result in someone storing something in a different place. What if a certain user stores some libraries in a subdirectory of their home folder, for example? I'm more looking for a good way of managing these dependencies.

Comment: It's not your concern, how users design their development environment. There are so many possibilities, you cannot  cover all of them. Just stay with `find_library` and let the user help CMake to find the library on their system. There are many examples out there, e.g. Boost provides the `Boost_ROOT` variable, and Qt provides the `Qt5_DIR` variable, so the user can give a hint on the location of the library.